# Using TransactionProxyFactoryBean with Spring and Hibernate

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, orm, configuration

I have an old project that I'm trying to upgrade to spring 4 / hibernate 4.

We use [this](https://www.nofluffjuststuff.com/blog/scott_leberknight/2006/01/declaring_transaction_attributes_on_spring_s_transactionproxyfactorybean) approach to configuring our transactions.

That is to say, in XML we define a transaction manager like:

```
<bean id="abstractTransactionProxy"
abstract="true"
class="org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionProxyFactoryBean">
<property name="transactionManager" ref="hibernateTransactionManager"/>
<property name="transactionAttributes">
    <props>
        <prop key="create*">PROPAGATION_REQUIRED</prop>
        <prop key="update*">PROPAGATION_REQUIRED</prop>
        <prop key="delete*">PROPAGATION_REQUIRED</prop>
        <prop key="*">PROPAGATION_SUPPORTS,readOnly</prop>
    </props>
</property>
```

and

```
<bean id="MySessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource"     ref="myDataSource" />
    <property name="configLocation" value="WEB-INF/hibernate.cfg.xml" />
</bean>
```

and then each of our service beans are defined like:

```
<bean id="customerService" parent="abstractTransactionProxy">
    <property name="target" ref="customerTarget"/>
    <property name="personDAO" ref="personDAO" />
</bean>
```

and the DAOs are defined like:

```
    <alias name="personDaoImpl" alias="personDAO"/>
<bean id="personDaoImpl" 
    class="com.foo.bar.hibernate.PersonDaoImpl">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="MySessionFactory" />
</bean>
```

PersonDaoImpl (and all the other DAOs) have many methods that look like this (all of the DAOs extend HibernateDaoSupport):

```
    public List<Person> getPersonByCriteria(final String criteria) {
    List<Person> results = 
        (List<Person>) this.getHibernateTemplate().executeFind(new HibernateCallback<List<Person>>(){

        public List<Person> doInHibernate(Session session) throws HibernateException, SQLException {
            List<Person> results = (List<Person>) session.createQuery(MYSQLHERE).setString("criteria", criteria).list();
            return results;
        }
    });
    return results;
}
```

Now, the problem I Face at this point is getting rid of our dependency on extending our DAOs from HibernateDaoSupport, and by extension, on using it's HibernateTemplate helper object.

Here's the steps I've taken:

- Simply remove them from the DAO methods - don't extend HibernateDaoSupport, remove the HibernateTemplate callback. This looks like:

  ```
      public List<Person> getPersonByCriteria(final String criteria) {
          List<Person> results = (List<Person>) getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession().createQuery(MYSQLHERE).setString("criteria", criteria).list();

          return results;
      }
  ```

Of course this gives me compile-time errors because 'getSessionFactory' was part of the base class 'HibernateDaoSupport' which I just removed.

- So I implemented a 'MyHibernateDaoSupport' Class, and had my DAO extend that instead. It looks like:

  ```
  public class MyHibernateDaoSupport {

      private SessionFactory sessionFactory;
      protected Session session;
      protected static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(MyHibernateDaoSupport.class);

      public void setSessionFactory(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
          this.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
          session = this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
      }

      public SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
      return this.sessionFactory;
      }

      public Session getHibernateTemplate() {
          session = this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
          return session;
      }

      public MyHibernateDaoSupport() {
      }
  ```

  }

Now I can build, deploy and run and I hit this error message:

```
No session available in this thread
```

How can I make this work?

- **In simple terms, what was the 'hibernateCallback()', and it's anoymous inner class actually doing?**
- **How can I make my project's transactions work as before, without using HibernateDaoSupport and HibernateTemplate classes?**

I've tried tagging my 'CustomerService' (the business logic object that calls 'PersonDao') with @transactional but (A) I see the same error regardless and (B) I'd really prefer to be able to do this programmatically, to reduce the scale of changes to the way the code works now. I also tried putting the transactions at the DAO level instead, and met the same issue.

Apologies if that was way too much detail for the Stack overflow format.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. You need to inject the SessionFactory into your DAO classes:

   ```
   @Repository
   public class PersonDAOImpl implements PersonDAO {

       @Autowired
       private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

       public List<Person> getPersonByCriteria(final String criteria) {
           List<Person> results = (List<Person>) getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession().createQuery(MYSQLHERE).setString("criteria", criteria).list();
           return results;
       }
   }
   ```
2. Add `@Transactional` to your service methods
3. Add [HibernateTransactionManager](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/4.1.6.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/orm/hibernate4/HibernateTransactionManager.html)
4. Instruct Spring to use declarative transactions:

   ```
   <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>
   ```
5. Make sure you use `LocalSessionFactoryBean` for creating the SessionFactory

Here's a detailed step-by-step [tutorial for configuring Spring and Hibernate 4](http://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-4-spring)

Comment: Step 5 is crutial and fixed the problem for us. Thanks